# No valid key mapping found for securityToken: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' and issuer

Tags: asp.net, authentication, saml, adfs, ws-federation

I am working on ADFS authentication using IDP page of ADFS.

I am able to redirect to IDP page successfully and also able to redirect back to my application successfully after getting authenticated.

Here I am getting below error message after returning back to my application:

> No valid key mapping found for securityToken:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' and issuer

I have added below code in web.config file to decrypt claims information.

```
 <authority name="http://idp.neuronetics.com/adfs/services/trust">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="‎‎1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234"/>
          </keys>`enter code here
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://adfsServiceDomain/adfs/services/trust" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
```

I have reviewed many articles related to this. Most of the articles suggest to verify the thumbprint of token signing certificate of ADFS.

I have double checked and the thumbprint is perfect.

Anyone have any idea regarding this issue ?

Please advise.

Please let me know if you have any concern or query or if you need more information.

Comment: Are you using OWIN Ws-Fed or WIF?

Comment: I am using Ws-Fed

Comment: I know that, the question is whether you use OWIN or WIF.

Comment: I m not using Owin. Just normal WIF. I know Owin is fetching thumbprint directly from Federation xml file, but it is not compatible with my system. so I m using normal WIF.

Comment: Ok, I provided an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WIF rather than OWIN, you can pretty much override the default issuer registry and provide your own one that gives you much more control over what issuers are accepted.

Overriding the issuer registry involves providing a class that inherits from the `IssuerNameRegistry`

```
public class CustomIssuerNameRegistry : IssuerNameRegistry
{
    public override string GetIssuerName( SecurityToken securityToken )
    {
        X509SecurityToken x509Token = securityToken as X509SecurityToken;
        if ( x509Token != null &&
             x509Token.Certificate != null
            )
        {
            // this is where you validate the certificate programatically
            // for example, you can verify the thumbprint against
            // a list of accepted thumprints

            // return a string, the name of the issuer to indicate
            // succesfull validation
            return "issuer name";
        }

        throw new SecurityTokenException( "Untrusted issuer." );
    }
```

and registering the issuer registry in the WIF pipeline in `web.config`

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <issuerNameRegistry type="Namespace.CustomIssuerNameRegistry, AssemblyName" />
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

This approach lets you debug incoming token's certificate thoroughly.